# Sorting list of positive words that most likely spoken by people at the top of list and the rarely spoken at end of list

Tags: c++, c

I have a list of positive words, the list has more than 1000 words. Is there any way to sort the list words from which one mostly to rarely spoken words? is there any idea how do it in C++ or C?
If I have static millions of csv tweets file and positive.txt file, does that work to make comparison to sort?

Comment: Read this file in your code ,they are already sorted and correspondingly sort yours  https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english

Answer (score 2):

This is called a self-organising list. Assuming you have a dataset, Knuth gives two algorithms:

- every time you find a used word, exchange it with its predecessor in the list, if any,

OR

- every time you find a used word, exchange it with the top item in the list.

After processing your dataset, your list should be more or less self-organised into frequency of use order.